# Using Subquery to update total column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE student_tests,
  (SELECT SUM(olc_sta_i_points_earned) AS total, olc_sta_i_stt_num FROM student_answers
     JOIN student_tests ON olc_sta_i_stt_num = olc_stt_i_num         
  ) AS a
SET student_tests.olc_stt_i_score = a.total
WHERE a.olc_sta_i_stt_num = student_tests.olc_stt_i_num
```

There are no errors but it says zero rows are affected.

Basically I have two tables: `student_tests` and `student_answers` the test id is mapped to the `student_answers` tables.  I want a subquery where I can sum all the student answers for the **specific** test id and then update the score column in the `student_tests` table in the tests table.

Am i doing something wrong with the where clause here? or is it something else?

Comment: Forget about the update. Can you write the select that produces the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should phrase this as an `update`/`join` explicitly, rather than having the `join` condition in the `where` clause.

Your problem is that you have no `group by` in the subquery.  The extra join to `student_tests` seems unnecessary, so try this:

```
UPDATE student_tests s JOIN
       (SELECT SUM(a.olc_sta_i_points_earned) AS total, a.olc_sta_i_stt_num
        FROM student_answers a     
        GROUP BY a.olc_sta_i_stt_num    
       ) AS a
       ON a.olc_sta_i_stt_num = t.olc_stt_i_num 
    SET s.olc_stt_i_score = a.total
```

Comment: Of course; not a `where` issue but a `group by` issue. let me check.